# android client image send NegativeArraySizeException

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am sending an image from my android gallery to a java server; however, I am getting a `NegativeArraySizeException`. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? I do not understand what the problem is. Thanks in advance.

**Android Client:**

```
Socket sock;
sock = new Socket("IP", PORT);
System.out.println("Connecting...");

OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();


File myFile = new File (selectedImagePath);
byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [(int)myFile.length()];
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
bis.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
System.out.println("Sending...");
os.write(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
os.flush();

sock.close();
```

**Java Server**

public class Receive {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

    byte[] sizeAr = new byte[4];
    InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();


    inputStream.read(sizeAr);
    int size = ByteBuffer.wrap(sizeAr).asIntBuffer().get();
```

System.out.println(size); // getting negative value

```
    byte[] imageAr = new byte[size];
    inputStream.read(imageAr);

    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageAr));

    System.out.println("Received " + image.getHeight() + "x" + image.getWidth() + ": " + System.currentTimeMillis());
    ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File("C:/Users/Dan/Pictures/NewCat.jpg"));

    serverSocket.close();
}
```

}

Comment: `The return value is unspecified if this pathname denotes a directory.` from https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#length()

Comment: an actual path to an image file is assigned to selectedImagePath. Any other ideas?

Comment: Post full stack trace and selectedImagePath.

Comment: There is not error on the android side. I get the exception on the java side. Sorry i should have been more clear when i posted this question.

Comment: selectedImagePath is /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Facebook/FB_IMG_1476672520973.jpg

Comment: Just posted the Java Server code.